# Using the backup gem how can I get database authentications details from rails database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backup

I'm testing out the backup gem

http://backup.github.io/backup/v4/utilities/

I understand that I've to create a db_backup.rb with the configuration for example

```
Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    # To dump all databases, set `db.name = :all` (or leave blank)
    db.name               = "my_database_name"
    db.username           = "my_username"
    db.password           = "my_password"
    db.host               = "localhost"
    db.port               = 3306
```

However I'm not able to find out how to get those details from the Rails `database.yml`. I've tried something like this:

```
  env = defined?(RAILS_ENV) ? RAILS_ENV : 'development'
  @settings = YAML.load(File.read(File.join( "config", "database.yml")))
```

But I guess there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
env = defined?(RAILS_ENV) ? RAILS_ENV : 'development'
config = YAML.load_file(File.join('config', 'database.yml'))[env]

Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    config.each_pair do |key, value|
      db.public_send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ActiveRecord's own configuration handling:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'

Model.new(:my_backup, 'My Backup') do
  database MySQL do |db|
    config = {
      # these are the default values
      host: 'localhost'
      port: 3306
    }.merge(load_configuration(ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'))
    config.each_pair do |key, value|
      db.public_send("#{key}=", value)
    end
  end

  # this loads the configuration from file and memoizes it
  def load_configuration(env)
    @file_config ||= YAML.load(File.read(File.join( "config", "database.yml")))  
    @configurations ||= ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling::MergeAndResolveDefaultUrlConfig.new(file_config).resolve
    @configurations[env]
  end
end
```

The key advantage here is that it will merge the values from `ENV['DATABASE_URL']`. Which is very important since you should avoid adding database credentials to `config/database.yml`.

A good habit is to specify only the connection adapter and base essentials in `database.yml`. Use `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` for usernames, passwords and everything else.

> Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any
>   code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being
>   checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config
>   files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they
>   are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.
>   - https://12factor.net/config

See:

- [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)